# "i8042 no controller found" error while trying to install ubuntu on Mac Book Pro early 2011

Tags: usb, mac, system, macbook-pro

Trying to install ubuntu with rEFInd on a mac book pro 15 early 2011 model.

"i8042 no controller found" error comes up and prevents installation. I have read the other answers regarding the topic but they have not worked such as running

"i8042.nomux" but it does not work or I am doing it wrong.

What is the problem? Any straightforward solutions?

Answer (score 1):

AskUbuntu user Velin knew how to fix this problem so I'm just reposting his answer:

For anyone else having this problem, it seems like it might be caused by a display driver issue. This can be fixed by adding the 'nomodeset' parameter in the kernel settings on startup. This instructs the kernel to not load video settings during startup but leave it to the X driver when it loads. This means no beautiful splash screen on startup but it beats a non-functional kernel.

The following link might be useful for people who don't know how to add the parameter: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

PS This issue might also be fixable by correcting video driver settings once the system is booted up. However, this still requires the above step for an initial boot.