# i8042: No controller found

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, 15.10, intel-graphics

There are other questions with the same issue ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567548/installing-ubuntu-on-early-2011-macbook-pro-using-usb-stick-i8042-no-controll) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655719/i8042-no-controller-found-error-while-trying-to-install-ubuntu-on-mac-book-pro)), but in my case, instead of a MacBook I have [this](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Dual-core-computer-Qotom-T4200U-8G-ram-1Tb-HDD-with-X86-Core-i5-4200U-Dual-Core/32531085419.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_10,searchweb201602_4_10017_10021_507_10022_10032_10020_10009_10008_10018_10019_101,searchweb201603_7&btsid=17247675-4cd4-4721-9c61-db9186bdc3ee) (I am not doing any kind of promotion of this product)

Until today, everything was working. I did not add or remove any hardware. The computer is running an ubuntu 15.10 with Gnome 3.18. Yesterday, the kernel was updated to the version 4.2.0-36-generic. Everything was working out of the box.

I tried [adding the `nomodeset` parameter to grub](https://askubuntu.com/a/620754/171961), also unplugging any USB device (except the keyboard). The error is the same if I try the previous kernel version.

As I do not have an up to date backup, re-install is the last option I want to try.

Answer (score 1):

It was not an issue with the i8042 controller (my fault)

After more research in this awesome place, I could understand that BusyBox comes up when the system could not mount the root filesystem.

As [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/148820/171961) suggest, starting a live Ubuntu and restoring a previous superblock will make it work.

The controller for i8042 seems to be a different issue :-)